# Calculating on grouped rows without loops

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `tidy` data set which describes attributes of products. Each product have many attributes, and each attribute is described in each row. My goal is to do some calculations on each product, without using loops. The reason for not wanting to use loops is that there are several hundreds of thousands of products, and thus many million attributes.

Toy dataset with only one product:

```
df <- data.frame(productID = 1, attributeID = seq(1,15,1), dataType = c('range', 'range', 'predefined', 'predefined', 'bool', 'bool', 'bool', 'bool', 'double', 'double', 'double', 'double', 'double', 'double', 'double'), double = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,15,11.4,6,0,0), logical = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), predefined = c(NA,NA,'Black','Round',NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), from.value = c(0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), to.value = c(249,368,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

   # productID attributeID   dataType double logical predefined from.value to.value
# 1          1           1      range     NA      NA       <NA>          0      249
# 2          1           2      range     NA      NA       <NA>          0      368
# 3          1           3 predefined     NA      NA      Black         NA       NA
# 4          1           4 predefined     NA      NA      Round         NA       NA
# 5          1           5       bool     NA    TRUE       <NA>         NA       NA
# 6          1           6       bool     NA   FALSE       <NA>         NA       NA
# 7          1           7       bool     NA   FALSE       <NA>         NA       NA
# 8          1           8       bool     NA   FALSE       <NA>         NA       NA
# 9          1           9     double    0.0      NA       <NA>         NA       NA
# 10         1          10     double    0.0      NA       <NA>         NA       NA
# 11         1          11     double   15.0      NA       <NA>         NA       NA
# 12         1          12     double   11.4      NA       <NA>         NA       NA
# 13         1          13     double    6.0      NA       <NA>         NA       NA
# 14         1          14     double    0.0      NA       <NA>         NA       NA
# 15         1          15     double    0.0      NA       <NA>         NA       NA
```

For example, how would one go about counting the zeros for each product in the `double` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're only after counting the number of zeros in the `double` column, the following should help:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(productID) %>% 
  summarise(sum.of.zeros=sum(double==0, na.rm = T))
```

The above sums the instances where `double` equals zero (if it equals zero, it would counted as 1 (`TRUE`) and if not it would be 0 (`FALSE`). The `na.rm = T` is required because the expression `NA==0` would return an `NA`.

Comment: You could also do `sum(double == 0, na.rm = T)`

Comment: Good point. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `tidyverse` packages, and `dplyr` in particular

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by( productID, from.value ) %>% summarise( amount = n_distinct( attributeID ))

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups:   productID [?]
#   productID from.value amount
#       <dbl>      <dbl>  <int>
# 1         1          0      2
# 2         1         NA     13
```

Comment: This can get a little messy if you change "from.value" with "double" in your answer, because then all unique values are listed (also all those that are not zero). Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: @pkg: not sure what you mean?  dplyr was made for these kind of jobs... You can always `round` the `double`-column if you wish to use that.. or create a new grouping-column based on the values in `double`

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table` you can do:

```
library("data.table")
setDT(df)[, sum(na.omit(double)==0), productID]
```

or

```
setDT(df)[, sum(double==0, na.rm=TRUE), productID]
```